# knockout-postbox and knockout components can you syncWith observable arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

I have two components that I want to sync an observable array between them.  It works find with an observable, but with an array it never syncs. Can you `syncWith` an observable array?

If I convert the array to string and then sync the observable it passes, but then I have to reconstruct the observable array on the other vm.  Can it be done with just a `syncWith`?

vm1

```
  self.offers = ko.observableArray([]).syncWith("offersLink");


            var mappedLogs = $.map(allData, function (item) { return new model.offerList(item) });
            self.offers(mappedLogs);
```

vm2

```
 self.offers = ko.observableArray([]).syncWith("offersLink");
```

Comment: What is not working? Item addition/removal to any of the `offers` array should be synced... however changes inside the items in the `offers` array won't be synced because the way how are observable arrays working (they don't check their children changes)

Comment: when I add data to vm1 vm2 still shows as empty.  Added some more code

Comment: Can you add a little more code to turn it into a reproducible snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

figured it out!

```
self.offers = ko.observableArray([]).syncWith("offersLink");
```

should be

```
self.offers = ko.observableArray().syncWith("offersLink");
```

[] was always overwriting with an empty array